# Get value of Store location onclick (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm currently working to get the value of a click in Javascript but I don't understand how to do it.

```
<span class="s-link">

<a class="s-link-pim-data" href="javascript:void(0);" target="_blank" title="Abrir en nueva ventana" onclick="$_retailerLocation('https://itrack.where-to-buy.co/wheretobuy/v1/WidgetClicks/?click=GUtc29uaWRvLXNhbXN1bmctaHctbTU1MHpmLTMxLWJsdWV0b290aC15LXN1Yndvb2Zlci1pbmFsYW1icmljbyUyRiZrZXk9NzcwNDRkMDRhY2JiNjZiYzM5Mjg4ZTI3ZjEyOWQ3NTAmY3VpZD17d3RiX2NsaWNrcmVmfQ%3D%3D&amp;ct=True','ElCorteIngles.es');return false;">ir</a>

</span>
```

In the code above I would like to get the value of "ElCorteIngles.es", after click.

I think the fact that the value is after a comma can help me?

Any ideas on how to proceed? I've been trying for four hours, but nothing's working

Comment: Is the function `$_retailerLocation` available to in your code?

Comment: No it is not accessible unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<span class="s-link">

<a class="s-link-pim-data" href="javascript:void(0);" target="_blank" title="Abrir en nueva ventana" onclick="$_retailerLocation('https://itrack.where-to-buy.co/wheretobuy/v1/WidgetClicks/?click=GUtc29uaWRvLXNhbXN1bmctaHctbTU1MHpmLTMxLWJsdWV0b290aC15LXN1Yndvb2Zlci1pbmFsYW1icmljbyUyRiZrZXk9NzcwNDRkMDRhY2JiNjZiYzM5Mjg4ZTI3ZjEyOWQ3NTAmY3VpZD17d3RiX2NsaWNrcmVmfQ%3D%3D&amp;ct=True','ElCorteIngles.es');return false;">ir</a>

</span>

<script>
 function $_retailerLocation(x, y){
   console.log(x, y)
}
</script>
```

Comment: I can't access to the function in the script.. but thank you :)

Comment: if it's not accessible in <script> then load the js file in your file
<script src="pathOfFileThatContain$_retailerLocation"></script>